# Firefox edit suggestions for single character input

Tags: firefox

In Firefox I can enter a single character into the URL bar and some sites are suggested. I believe in the past I saw a possibility to edit the sites that are being suggested. Is it possible via `about:config` or the like?

Answer (score 0):

If the object is to make a bookmark appear higher in the list returned from searces so that typing a letter (or two) acts as a "hot key", there are two things to do:

First, you can specify only certain sources for suggestions with `about:config` for the following, self-explanatory, keys:

- browser.urlbar.suggest.bookmark
- browser.urlbar.suggest.history
- browser.urlbar.suggest.searches

Set them to `false` to stop that type of suggestion.

Second, in `userChrome.css` (which you may need to [create](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css&printable=yes)), add the following to cause your bookmarks to appear at the top of the list:

```
/* Search bar result order: bookmarks, history, then other tabs */
#PopupAutoCompleteRichResult .autocomplete-richlistitem[type="bookmark"]{  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 0; }
#PopupAutoCompleteRichResult .autocomplete-richlistitem[type="favicon"]{   -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1; }
#PopupAutoCompleteRichResult .autocomplete-richlistitem[type="switchtab"]{ -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2; }
```

*Caveat:* This does not force Search to return just a single result, but it does move frequently-used bookmarks higher. Rename your preferred bookmarks with mnemonics to reduce the returned clutter .